# LocationListener is causing memory leak in android

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have implemented to get the user's current location when user clicked the agreement button. I have implemented the **LocationListener**  in the activity and I have unregistered the listener at both ***onStop*** and ***onDestroyed***. But according to ***LeakCanary***, memory leak is still existing.
[image]

This is a brief of My code.

```
public class UserProfileEditActivity extends BaseActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, LocationListener, LocationResult {   
LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationHelper myLocation;
    LocationResult locationResult;
public void getCurrentUserLocation() {

        myLocation.getLocation(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        myLocation = new LocationHelper(locationManager, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        reset();
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        reset();
        super.onDestroy();
}

//implementation of LocationResult
   @Override
public void gotLocation(Location location) {
    //Got the location!
    getCurrentUserHomeTown(location);
    if (location != null)
        showLog("Location lat :" + location.getLatitude() + " long :" + location.getLongitude());
}

private void reset() {
        if (confirmationDialog != null)
            confirmationDialog.dismiss();
        if (myLocation != null) {
            myLocation.stopLocationListeners();
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationResult = null;
            locationManager = null;
            myLocation = null;
        }
    } 



 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
```

And this is how I trigger to gather location.

```
 public void getCurrentUserLocation() {

        myLocation.getLocation(this);
    }
```

this is ***LocationHelper.class***

```
public class LocationHelper {

    private LocationResult locationResult;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;

//    private Timer timer;

    private LocationListener locationListener;


    public LocationHelper(LocationManager locationManager, LocationListener locationListener) {
        this.locationManager = locationManager;
        this.locationListener = locationListener;

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public boolean getLocation(LocationResult result) {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult = result;

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if (gps_enabled)
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, (float) 10.0, locationListener);
        if (network_enabled)
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, (float) 10.0, locationListener);
        getLastLocation();
//        timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(locationManager, locationListenerGps, locationListenerNetwork, gps_enabled, network_enabled, locationResult), 40000);
        return true;
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getLastLocation() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

        Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
        if (gps_enabled)
            gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (network_enabled)
            net_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //if there are both values use the latest one
        if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
            if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime())
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            else
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }

        if (gps_loc != null) {
            locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            return;
        }
        if (net_loc != null) {
            locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }
        locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }

    public void stopLocationListeners() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
//        if (timer != null) {
//            timer.cancel();
//            timer = null;
//        }
        locationListener = null;
        locationResult = null;
        locationManager = null;
    }

}
```

But the ***LeakCanary*** keep indicating there is memory leak with ***LocationManager*** and ***LocationListener***. Please Help me find out this.

Comment: The `locationManager` and `myLocation` variables in `UserProfileEditActivity` are package-private...does any external class/code need access to these variables?

Comment: Where do I have to use applicationContext? I have use applicationContext everywhere context is needed. @Blackbelt

Comment: Nope. Those variables are only accessed in the class . I will change them to private. But can it cause a memory leak ? @Leo

Comment: No, they shouldn't cause any memory leak by itself

Comment: So any idea about what could behind those leaks > @Leo

Comment: I have no idea tbh. I'll try to set up a test project later when I get home and see if I help you find it

Comment: Your code as it is in this post has no leaks. Tested on a Mate 20 Pro and Galaxy S10+

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Leo. If so, the leak canary is showing the wrong leak. I have tested the above code on xiaomi Mi6 , One Plus 6T ,samsung a7 (2015) and an emulator.

Comment: Is this code running on an activity or a fragment?

Comment: It's running on an activity. Now I have changed the LocationHelper class to https://gist.github.com/emil2k/5381596 , then the leak has gone into thin air. Thanks for your effort @Leo .